# I did npm i -g npm@5.5.1 after that I am not able see npm -v , throwing error

Tags: node.js, npm, automation, backend, node-modules

```
 npm -v
```

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:

Before this npm -v showing 8. some version
but now it's throwing error
how can i resolve this or undo?

Comment: try deleting your %appdata%/npm-cache folder.. and try repair or re-install again. 
this works for me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below command if you are using Linux:
It will clean install the latest version of npm. It will also remove the previous version of npm

```sh
sudo curl -qL https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: I am using windows , please tell for that

Comment: Simple.. uninstall your node and npm and reinstall them. Simple as it is.

Comment: I already did , what I did Is uninstall node and install it again, but can you please tell I need to separately uninstall npm , If yes then please tell how?

Comment: no... when you uninstall node, It automatically uninstalls npm too.. check whether npm works as intended and let me know the results

Comment: again , it's showing the same behavior  npm -v
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:

Comment: Try the repair option in the installer of node which u used to install node previously.

Comment: ya , that also did but same

Comment: try deleting your `%appdata%/npm-cache` folder.. and try repair or re-install again.

Comment: its done buddy, tysm................................

Comment: np... Happy coding.